# Creating a new column title in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which looks like the below:

[image: Spreadsheet with dates in columns]

I am trying to write a macro (and ultimately a button) which will create a new column with the current date as a header in the first empty column i.e. next to april it will say May if I run it when it is May.

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub column()

Dim Input_ID As String, Date_in As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Facebook")
Date_in = Format(Now, "MMM-YY")

With ws.Range("2" & ws.Columns.Count).End(xlUp)
    If .column >= c Then .Offset(1, 0).Value = Date_in Else Exit Sub
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a rather vague problem statement. Can you clarify? Since you're new here you might want to read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513) on meta, to ensure you're asking useful questions about *specific* coding issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub AddColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Facebook")

    ws.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ws.Range("C1").Value = Format(Now(), "MMM-YY")

End Sub
```

Comment: Since OP is new to VBA, and this is a rather vague "please do the work for me" question, wouldn't it be more helpful to provide at least a bit of an explanation of what your solution is doing, instead of encouraging copy-pasta coding and not teaching anything?

Answer (score 3):

First we need to find the last populated cell in your worksheet, in this case we will find it by going to the last cell in row 2:

```
ws.Cells(2, .Columns.Count)
```

Then once we are on the last cell in row 2, we go all the way to the left in the same row using the `.End(xlToLeft)` property to find the last cell with data and then store the column index number in the variable `LastCol` as we will need it.

```
LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
```

As we said `LastCol` its not the actual next empty column, so we add 1 to the `LastCol` variable to target the next empty column.

Finally we place the `Date_in` string value in the next empty column in row 2

```
.Cells(2, LastCol + 1) = date_in
```

Complete code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub column()

Dim Input_ID As String, date_in As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
date_in = Format(Now, "MMM-YY")

With ws

LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
.Cells(2, LastCol + 1) = date_in

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Since OP is new to VBA, and this is a rather vague "please do the work for me" question, wouldn't it be more helpful to provide at least a bit of an explanation of what your solution is doing, instead of encouraging copy-pasta coding and not teaching anything?

Comment: I agree with you @Mathieu Guindon, added explanation, hope it is clear for the OP and everyone.